# Android Build Strings is driving me mad

Tags: java, android, string

While building strings is confusing me. If I do this:

```
String line;
String webreponse ;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     webreponse = webreponse + line;
} // while reader != null
```

Eclipse says: "The local variable webreponse may not have been initialized" and makes me do this:

```
String line = null;
String webreponse = null ;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      webreponse = webreponse + line;
} // while reader != null
```

But, then I end up with: "nullSome Strings added on" the NULL is added. Of course if I change String webreponse = ""; to empty string it works but, that is generally a bad approach as I just initialized the var webresponse when it's not supposed to be (and can't check for null later)!

Of course I have also tried using string builder and the alike but, string builder initialized as null gives me: "this var can only be null at this point NPE"

Seriously, it's like a sea saw, leave it as "String webreponse" and I get compiler error, put in "String webreponse = null" I get null in my string and put in String webreponse = ""; and i've initialized a variable that shouldn't be...

What is the "right" why to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in Java are *immutable*. Every time you use the concatenation operator (`+`) you're actually creating a new `String` object.

Because you're starting with your `String` being `null` ... the conversion during the concatenation results in the word "null" in the result (this is specified in the JLS when using string concatenation).

You *could* simply start with an empty `String` (e.g. `String webresponse = ""`) but that's still really inefficient due to the aforementioned immutability.

You want to use a `StringBuilder`:

```
String line;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line);
}
```

**Edit:**

I just noticed: *" that is generally a bad approach as I just initialized the var webresponse when it's not supposed to be (and can't check for null later)!"*

`String` does provide a `.isEmpty()` method ... so I don't know what advantage `null` gives you, but you could simply check the length of the `StringBuilder`

```
String webresponse = null;
if (sb.length() > 0)
{
    webresponse = sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: No question this is the superior approach in terms of efficiency. However, I don't think it is germane to the OP's question.

Comment: ah! Perfect! Thanks, and to make sure webResponse is Null when empty: String webResponse = null; then If (sb.length > 0) webResponse = sb.tostring();

Comment: @Wilmsoft Yeah, I just caught that and edited, actually.

Comment: @Pedantic, because the OP framed this as a question about initialization state and preconditions rather than optimization. But the OP likes the answer given his or her fondness for `null` and `null` checks despite all the wisdom that advocates otherwise, so what do I know? Haha.

Comment: Old habits die hard I suspect but, null to me means "Not worked on" so, no point in doing any other work or checks on it. It SHOULD be worked on but, if not: if (text != null) tells me don't worry about doing any thing else with it. also I tried .isEmpty() as well but, it required API level 9, this old code is level 8 :(

Answer (score 0):

In java you have to give default value to local variables. Local variables are those variables which are defined within methods. So you need to initialize your local variable with default value. You have defined with Null. So when you concatenate with this. It will add "Null" + your other values. To avoid this you can initalize your local variable with empty string e.q String ab="";

Second you are using String to concatenation is wrong. You are creating lots of String object. Instead you can use StringBuilder or StringBuffer. Right approach is to use StringBuilder if you are not worry about synchronization.